# CVSS attack vector adjacent vs network

Tags: vulnerability, attack-vector, cvss

I am trying to calculate a CVSS score for a vulnerability. In my case, to exploit the vulnerability you should have network access to the server, which is sitting behind a firewall. This server is serving an application that only computers with network access can benefit from, so it's not on the Internet.

I assume from my understanding this should be Adjacent. Do you agree? If not please someone explain how I can differentiate between adjacent and network.

Comment: If the server ***was*** connected directly to the internet, would it be exploitable? Or is the *nature* of the vulnerability such that you would have to be on the locally adjacent network? CVSS is to describe the vulnerability, not the context in which you discovered the vulnerability or the specific configuration of the subject of evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding CVSS 3.1 specification :

> When deciding between Network and Adjacent, if an attack can be
> launched over a wide area network or from outside the logically
> adjacent administrative network domain, use Network. Network should be
> used even if the attacker is required to be on the same intranet to
> exploit the vulnerable system (e.g., the attacker can only exploit the
> vulnerability from inside a corporate network).

My understanding is that if your component can be targeted from another logical network (example : another VLAN), even if it's in the same intranet, then the parameter should be set to "Network".

Source: https://www.first.org/cvss/v3.1/specification-document

Comment: OKay but in what cases then it is adjacent ?

Comment: It's adjacent when the attacker need to be on the same network segment (same VLAN, same IP subnet, etc ...). An example given by CVSS specification is attack relative to ARP protocol. A more (maybe too) easy way to understand it is that it's adjacent when it can't work if there is a layer 3 device (router for example) between the attacker and the target.